How to lazy import a CSS file created by Tailwind in NextJS?
I check my site performance in GTMETRIX and it says : Eliminate render-blocking resources.

I use NextJS & Tailwind.
GTMETRIX says for solve the probolm use this:

A  tag that appears in the  of the document and doesn't have a defer or async attribute.
A  tag that does not have a disabled or media attribute.
A  tag that does not have an async attribute.

How can I set these attributes in NextJS14? While next automatically creates the CSS and puts it in the header


I think this is a false positive. the stylesheet generated by Tailwind should be critical.
